# the make command on NppExec is not working on windows?

Tags: windows, makefile, cmd, notepad++, nppexec

I am trying to build a save, make and run function on notepad++ for C++.
I am working on the plugin called NppExec, and my script looks like this:

NPP_SAVE

cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)

cmd /k qmake *.pro &  "C:\Program Files\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe"

I did write the directory of the ming32-make.exe into path but it's not working so I decided to do it this way.
So the thing is if I compile it from NppExec, the msg shows as follows

```
C:/Program Files/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/fox/Desktop/code/test'
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -O2 -std=gnu++11 -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -    I"C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\include\QtCore" -Irelease -I"C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\mkspecs\win32-g++"  -o release\main.o main.cpp
g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
Makefile.Release:107: recipe for target 'release/main.o' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release/main.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/fox/Desktop/code/test'
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2
```

It's fairly weird when I ran the command directly in cmd, it means I went to the directory of the Makefile and run the mingw32-make.exe it did compile and created the executable.
how come?

Comment: No idea, but `-    I"C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\include"` on the g++ command line (several spaces between the "-" and the "I") sure looks suspicious,

Comment: @ReluctantBIOSGuy hi, after I restarted notepad++ several times, it suddenly started to compile the code successfully. I don't know why...but it worked...I suppose it has something to do with NppExec's cmd emulator.